# How do I execute this instrument approach at Larnaca (LCLK)?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, instrument-procedures, iaps

I am on course 200 degrees and got a clearance for the VOR-ILS X RWY 22 approach at [Larnaca International Airport (LCLK)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larnaca_International_Airport):

[image]

Where is the/an IAF in this case? Do I have to join a holding pattern over the LCA VOR for a course reversal to course 041 inbound to the VOR, and then another base turn for a course reversal to the final approach course?

Comment: It would be helpful to know where you are (position and altitude) when you receive the clearance.

Comment: Let's say  20 nm out of LCA at 6000ft

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find LCLK charts anywhere online. But, would you actually be cleared for that approach from that direction? That is, isn't there another, more direct, option?

Answer (score 3):

If you're course 200 then you are more than 30 degrees off the initial outbound track of the approach, therefore you should join the hold prior to commencing.

In more practical terms, if you're VMC at any point and your happy with your terrain clearance, then there would be nothing to preclude a request for a straight in, although from experience, LCA can get busy!